# Question about Relations - Reflexive, Symmetric, Transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

Here is the question:

Given A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}. Determine which of the following
relations from A to A are reflexive, symmetric, and transitive, respectively:

• R1 = {(1, 1),(2, 2),(1, 2),(2, 3),(3, 2),(3, 3),(4, 4),(5, 5),(7, 6),(6, 7),(6, 6),(2, 1),(7, 7)};

• R2 = {(1, 2),(2, 3),(1, 3),(1, 4),(2, 4)};

• R3 = {(1, 4),(2, 5),(3, 7),(6, 6)};

• R4 = {(2, 4),(4, 2),(4, 6),(2, 6),(6, 4),(6, 2),(2, 2),(4, 4),(6, 6)}.

I have some questions about R2 to R4. For R1, this is reflexive, symmetric, and not transitive. But I am a little bit confused about R2 - R4. Since some of the vertexes have never been visited(like 5,6,7 in R2). If that kind of vertex exists, then it will be not reflexive, not symmetric, and not transitive right? I am confused about wheater I need to exclude them or not. If I include them as a vertex in the graph. Then R2 - R4 will come up with the same result, which is not reflexive, not symmetric, and not transitive. If not, the result will be totally different. Can anyone explain to me this? Thanks

Comment: $R_1$ should be symmetric. Here is a way to look at this for symmetric and reflexive. If you make an $n\times n$ matrix and put a $1$ in the $(i,j)$th entry if $(i,j)$ is in the relation, then if the matrix is symmetric then the relation is symmetric, and if there are $1$'s on the diagonal, then it is reflexive.

Comment: Even if you use the "other result" as you say, it will not be true. Consider $(1, 1)$.

Comment: And R4 will be symmetric, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose no ordered pair in the relation $R$ involves $x\in A$. This absence does *not* disqualify $R$ from being symmetric or transitive. Consider the symmetric property:
$$\forall a,b\in A:aRb\to bRa$$
If $a=x$ or $b=x$ there is no way to make $aRb$ true, so the implication is *vacuously* true with respect to $x$. Thus $x$ can safely be ignored when checking for the property.

The same goes for the transitive property
$$\forall a,b,c\in A:aRb\land bRc\to aRc$$
Because of $\land$, if any of $a,b,c$ is $x$ the whole LHS must be false, and we have another vacuous truth with respect to $x$.

Comment: +1. In particular if $R=\emptyset$ then $R$ is symmetric and transitive.